# Python: PySVN checkout and update certain directories

Tags: python-3.x, svn, pysvn

I am using PySVN to checkout and update from a repo but don't want to checkout the entire repo.  I only want certain folders and files so I am thinking I need to a sparse checkout and update on the files and folders i want.

My repo structure (example)

```
\Repo1
    \animals
       \dogs
        \cats
        \fish
     \automobiles
        \cars
        \motorcycles
      \aircraft
```

I can do a sparse checkout via the following code of a single directory with the following code:

```
def run_remote(client,remote_path, local_path):
    # sparse checkout
    client.checkout(remote_path, local_path,depth=pysvn.depth.empty)

def update_remote(client,update_local_test_path, local_path):
    client.update(update_local_test_path,depth=pysvn.depth.infinity)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import pysvn
    import os
    import pprint

DESKTOP_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'Desktop')
REPO_SVN_URL = "https://snv-test/repo1"
REMOTE_TEST_PATH = "https://snv-test/repo1/animals"
LOCAL_TEST_PATH = os.path.join(DESKTOP_PATH, 'repo1')
#c:\users\desktop\repo1
UPDATE_LOCAL_TEST_PATH = os.path.join(LOCAL_TEST_PATH, 'animals')
#c:\users\desktop\repo1\animals
  
client = pysvn.Client()
client.callback_get_login = login
client.callback_notify = notify

run_remote(client, REMOTE_TEST_PATH, LOCAL_TEST_PATH)

update_remote(client, UPDATE_LOCAL_TEST_PATH, LOCAL_TEST_PATH)

# FUTURE: LOOP THROUGH DIRECTORIES AND DO MULTIPLE UPDATES

# FUTRE: UPDATE DIRECTORIES BY REVISION

# FUTURE: GET CURRENT REVISION NUMBERS
```

My code runs the checkout successfully and creates a local folder called 'repo1' that is empty.  The update runs with no errors, but does not perform any update.  Meaning, no folders are added to the 'repo1' folder.  I was expecting the 'animals" directory with all folders and files to be updated locally.  I suspect i do not have my update arguments correct.

The ultimate goal is to have a list of directories i want to be able to configure to automate a checkout/update and even do an update by revision eventually.  Just want to get the checkout and update working.  I am sure there may be more efficient was to do this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: SVN should not need a checkout plus an update, just checkout the (sub) directories you want. I am not familiar with PySVN but that `pysvn.depth.empty` does not look correct. I would recommend to use the infinite value there. bTW where is `REMOTE_TEST_PATH` defined?

Comment: Thank the reply.  1.) I had attempted multiple checkouts but on the second checkout (e.g. 'animals' folder), get the "repo1" is already a working copy for a different URL" error. 2.)  Updated the remote_test_path, that was removed by accident when creating the post.

Comment: You can't check-out a repo into a repo, use for each repository a different new folder empty not reflecting the structure within the SVN repository. For example check-out every animal into an own sub-folder.